# How do you run a websockets server and normal HTTP webserver on the same port with Haskell?

Tags: haskell, websocket, socket.io

I've been programming a websocket server using [Network.WebSockets](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/websockets/0.6.0.4/doc/html/Network-WebSockets.html).

You start up a websockets server with `runServer` like this:

```
app :: Request -> WebSockets Hybi00 ()
app _ = app1
main :: IO ()
main = runServer "0.0.0.0" 8000 app
```

But I would really like the websockets server to run out of port 80 along with a normal Snap webserver.

Node.js is capable of doing this with Socket.io (see http://socket.io/#how-to-use on the left example).

Here is a Ruby library that achieves something similar: https://github.com/simulacre/sinatra-websocket

How would one do this in Haskell?

Comment: The [websockets-snap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets-snap) package is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: How would you do Snap routing to insert a websockets handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [websockets-snap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets-snap) package has a function:

runWebSocketsSnap :: Protocol p => (Request -> WebSockets p ()) -> Snap ()

This should let you use websockets from almost any place in your application.  Here's a simple example:

```
main = quickHttpServe $ route [ ("hello", writeText "hello world")
                              , ("websocket", runWebSocketsSnap ...)
                              ]
```

Comment: This does work, but then I noticed that the websocket connection kept disconnecting after about a minute. I tried tinkering with the defaultTimeout setting but to no effect...

Comment: Try using snap-core's [timeout API](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap-core/0.9.2.2/doc/html/Snap-Core.html#g:13)

Comment: I tried that as well, and the websocket still gets killed in about a minute regardless of the setting.

Comment: @dan Try using `WS.startPingThread 30` as soon as the client connects. That way, you ensure there is periodic activity on the websocket, and snap should not kill it that way.

Comment: Hi @jaspervdj thanks. You meant `spawnPingThread` of course. I'm trying it now, but it required me to change the WS protocol my WS loop is using from Hybi00 to Hybi10. I guess there is no way to pingThread on Hybi00 (the most widely supported)?

Comment: runWebSocketsSnap now spawns a ping thread automatically, and will extend the timeout when a pong is received by "WS.receiveDataMessage". However, using "WS.receive", or never receiving any messages within the handler will let timeout expire. In that case, use 'Snap.getTimeoutModifier' and pass to the websocket handler, as suggested by @mightybyte.

Answer (score 3):

Warp provides hooks for for promoting a regular HTTP request to a WebSockets request. I don't know what the preferred server is for Snap... This is the pattern I use for a Warp/WAI app:

```
httpApp :: Application
httpApp req = ...

wsApp :: WebSockets.Request -> WebSockets Hybi10 ()
wsApp req = do
   -- check if the request should be handled
   if shouldHandleRequest
     then do
       acceptRequest
       ...

     else rejectRequest ...

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let settings = Warp.defaultSettings
        {settingsIntercept = WebSockets.intercept wsApp}

  Warp.runSettings settings httpApp
  return ()
```